# Make comment flagging more public

Tags: feature-request, etiquette, comment-flags, welcoming

As of May 2018 [Stack Overflow has 9.1m visits per day and 8.8m users](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic). There are [1.69m](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/849742/users-able-to-flag) users with the ability to flag. **81% of all Stack Overflow users either don't know that flagging is possible or have no ability to do so.**

Whether or not you agree that [*Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) there is plenty of evidence that any number of individuals feel put off by the site <sup>[1](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d), [2](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7szv7i/anyone_else_find_the_stack_overflow_community/), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242490/why-does-se-appear-a-rather-unfriendly-environment-for-new-users-and-how-can-we), [5](http://geekthis.net/post/why-stackoverflow-is-awful/), [6](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stack+overflow+is+toxic)</sup>. This post is not about whether those individuals are right or not. For the purposes of this suggestion, it doesn't matter; what matters is the *perception* that they have.

**We have a site that is perceived to be unfriendly in which 4/5 of all visitors might not even know that we care.** Given the amount of effort that goes into ensuring that rude comments and posts are removed as soon as possible this seems sub-optimal.

Why not show *everyone* that Stack Overflow, and Stack Exchange, *does* care? Give them the opportunity to be part of the solution.

I propose that the ability to flag comments is opened up to all visitors (and/or users).

<sub>This is an updated restatement of [one of my MSE answers from 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218538/179419).</sub>

---

To be realistic this will increase the number of comment flags, and potentially the number of people being vindictive with their flagging. I don't see that a feature request necessarily needs to solve potential issues, but here are some options:

The expected increase in flags could be taken care of via the current auto-deletion rules, or a more stringent variety of them for users who do not currently have the privilege. There are [some other suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138149/179419). A/B testing can be performed in advance to project the likely impact.

For users, the current checks on voting rings and the rate-limits should limit revenge flagging, for visitors an rate-limiting in the same way as questions should mitigate.

Comment: I'd support this as an experiment, to find out what type of comment this tends to get flagged.

Comment: A more restricted version of this would be to allow the post author to flag comments on his question/answer rather than on any post at all. Making the flag option more visible on comments might be required too, it's not the most discoverable thing in the UI (IMO).

Comment: Users can flag at 15 rep. If they cannot contribute even this little to the site then why would we want flag noise from said users?

Comment: Does anyone know if too many unhelpful flags causes some sort of flag privilege revocation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first comment @Monkey. Only 20% of visitors have 15 rep, there is no contribution from 80% of users.

Comment: @Mat I'm thinking along the same lines... Users with 1 rep can always flag their own posts for moderator attention (but I know I've forgotten that's a thing in the past - so it's very unlikely a new user is going to realise that) - would it be that bad letting them flag comments on their own posts as well... I'm trying to think if there's an obvious: "nope - that's a terrible idea" I'm missing

Comment: @MonkeyZeus none on comment flags - it's only applied to post flags.

Comment: Where is SO going to get the 50 additional moderators from?

Comment: @MartinJames mod election announcement in 3, 2, 1, ....

Comment: @JonClements Only *registered* users can flag their own posts with 1 rep. For an *unregistered* user, there is a flag button, but it does nothing when clicked.

Comment: @Ben Exactly. If 80% of users cannot even attain 15 rep then what makes them qualified to flag something? I've had users flat out tell me that I am rude and they are flagging my comment because I asked for clarification about an aspect of their question. That seems like a waste of time for a moderator, no?

Comment: @PaulWhite yes... I should have been more explicit :)

Comment: "cannot even attain 15 rep" seems quite arrogant @Monkey. Just because someone doesn't have any questions doesn't mean someone hasn't been rude on the site and that a user has noticed it. I'm unsure why you think a mod needs to get involved - there are auto-deletion rules at the moment. Combined with the question rate-limiting that might easily stop mods having to be involved at all.

Comment: @Ben: 15 rep is just 7 suggested edits.

Comment: So change "doesn't have any questions" to "hasn't edited any posts" then @Cerbrus.

Comment: Our point is that it only requires _minimal_ effort to get past that 15 rep threshold. If that's too much work, maybe it's not such a bad thing that they can't flag?

Comment: @Ben so puippets and ring-voters can get rid of annoying users who downvote their bad questions without any meat-moderation at all?  No thanks.  Also, describing users as 'arrogant' in a comment can be seen as rude and unwelcoming.

Comment: @Ben If anonymous users are contributing to automatic deletion of posts then that's even worse.  Rather than consuming moderator time it will simply result in anyone who wants to being able to unilaterally delete anything they want by just logging out and flagging a post 6 times in a row.  The opportunities for abuse there are both trivial to do and extremely problematic.

Comment: @Ben This sounds heinously open to gamification of the system and abuse by any audience that has an "axe to grind". If flagging is opened to visitors/users with no "skin in the game" then what incentive do they have to behave properly?

Comment: Why would the current question rate-limiting system not work @Monkey? Why does it matter whether we think it might be open to gamification if SE says that they can prevent it?

Comment: This is only comments @Martin - no posts at all. CC Servy.

Comment: @Ben I think you lost me. What does "question rate-limiting" have to do with the comment flagging free-for-all concept?

Comment: 'there is plenty of evidence' off-site rants on reddit etc, by a disaffected few is not good evidence and does not supprt radical action to fix the problem.  The only SE link you provided was rebutted in an answer with +28 votes.  There is hardly any reliable/quantifiable evidence.

Comment: @Ben So in other words you think it's perfectly fine for anyone in the world to unilaterally remove any comment, at any time, for any reason, with no checks or balances, because they're comments and not posts?  That's nonsensical.  Sure, it'd be *worse* if it was for posts too, but it's still *bad* to let anyone anonymously delete any comment.

Comment: @Ben as long as it's "on your post", I'm ok with this. If not, what stops me from asking my FB friends for "please register an account there and flag this as rude/abusive". With enough flags the comment will be deleted (and there may even be the rep penalty? I'm not sure about that part), whether the flags are right or not.

Comment: I agree with the goal (making people know we care) but not with the way. And actually... I really doubt that the target people mentioned here care that we care.

Comment: Honestly, this idea could even have a negative effect by opening Stack Overflow to other unnecessary scrutiny such as "Look! Stack Overflow is clearly not a good place if they need mass public help to flag their content so you should use Quora/experts-exchange/Yahoo answers!"

Comment: @Patrice The proposal is to allow anonymous flags, so there's no need for you to get FB friends, or for anyone to create an account, you just need to log out and start casting flags.

Comment: @Servy even worse..... And an even bigger reason for "on your own posts only"

Comment: Lemme present some Reddit evidence /s : [An example of Stack Overflow being egregiously hostile to user3840485, a woman of color, by closing a very common question as off-topic even though an answer would benefit many people. : stackoverflow](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/8fuhgj/an_example_of_stack_overflow_being_egregiously/)

Comment: @brasofilo well, I'm sure that's evidence of something:)

Comment: @brasofilo I literally cannot even...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I suspect the person is a professional troll. It's the only logical explanation; well, that or Flat Earth...

Comment: @brasofilo Maybe, but those are rather docile conclusions. I'm starting to wonder if we're finally starting to see the true side-effects of Tide Pod consumption.

Comment: @Martin, I just noticed that not commenting on sub-par, sub-standard, sub-50, sub-10 questions has a purificational effect. You found a golden rule, mate, pure gold indeed, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a few things worth doing, as we look at this problem of comments a little more holistically.

Rudeness and condescension is just *one* of the problems we get from leaving text boxes laying around on the Internet like that; it's hard when you call what we *intended* to be "short discussions discussing something that should lead to an edit" *comments*, because that's pretty far from what most people that have ever used the Internet would guess as our intended meaning.

#### So, we can't let the place burn down while we figure out how to put fires out.

That's to say, we have to be willing to take some stop-gap measures we know we're likely to throw away later *if and when* we finally make comments better illustrate their intended purpose, and seem as if they were intentional from the beginning and not a bolted-on afterthought.

So to do that, what I think makes sense is:

- Allow users to flag comments on their own posts, always.
- At least *test* what flagging would look like if we open the privilege up to any registered user. Run this in short A/B groups at different times of day, and on different days (including weekends) to see what we can learn
- Look at what actually gets flagged (well, in testing), and then feed that data back into the bigger UX overhaul as well as efforts to better identify what upsets people. We know we've got problems with what's not blatantly rude, let's surface as much of that as we can, and then discuss the data while releasing it for lots of very smart people here to work with.

#### Bigger picture, we probably have to get rid of comments as we know them.

I think we need to be much more deliberate about what problem we intend comments to solve *outside of giving people a more obvious place to type a comment instead of in an answer field*.

Do we *want* punditry, or do we want edits that someone was ready to suggest but held off until they could collaborate with the author a bit? We really want the second, and we need to decide if we want that at the cost of the first, because having both creates a ton of noise and work and has for quite some time.

We can't just say "Oh, flag it" when we know good and well there's already a thousand flags in the backlog. That's writing checks our mods can't cash, and while the community could ramp up and do more there, wouldn't there be better uses for that time?

I'm going to link this to the Trello card on our sprint board for discovery surrounding strategy in fixing comments and defer it. While the original idea might not scale well, I think the discussion under it is something we can move on, so let's see where it goes.

Comment: _Get rid of comments_ > Lose any chance of having the OP fix their low quality / unanswerable question, and a massive increase in NAA "comment" answers. It's an _extremely_ drastic measure that can't possibly have a positive outcome

Comment: @Cerbrus Note, I said as we know them. We'll probably need to build a more robust feedback loop for that sort of help.

Comment: I can't see how, but that's why I'm a developer and not an inventor ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus - What if there was an "improvement request" system like what was being worked towards in Documentation? Instead of freeform comments, having a queue of issues that people point out with a question / answer in a more organized manner?

Comment: @BradLarson: I think that would be too much “stuff” to deal with. It would be too complicated. What’s so great about comments, is their simplicity. You don’t need to track issues, all you can do is reply, or edit your post.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Treating comments as "issues" with a post might allow for a more structured system for dealing with the problems in a question / answer, as well as a means of removing those issues / downvotes when corrected (perhaps by a notification to the person raising the issue). We group flags and close votes to aid processing and handle common cases quickly, maybe bringing a little structure to comments might do the same there.

Answer (score 23):

> *"I propose that the ability to flag comments is opened up to all visitors (and/or users)."*

Oh god no.

We don't want every single newly registered user flagging whatever they want to flag. The reason the ability to flag is hidden behind a [15 rep wall](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), is to make sure users know at least *something* about how SO works, and to prevent throwaway accounts from going on a flagging rampage.

Especially the "Rude/Abusive" and "Spam" flags have *serious* repercussions for the flagged users:

- Loss of rep or even suspensions on flagged questions / answers.
- Automatic removal of comments that receive multiple "R/A" flags.

This way, it's too easy to "silence" someone you disagree with. Just create a few accounts and start flagging...

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't apply to **comments** though which is what the OP is suggesting here...

Comment: @JonClements: Updated. better?

Comment: There are no repercussions, but if there are there's no reason why they can't be removed from users who don't currently have the privilege. Otherwise you seem to be focusing on the mechanics of preventing gaming the system.

Comment: Your last concern would be alleviated by Mat's suggestion in the comments that <15 users can only flag comments on *their own* posts... You don't need 15 rep to be able to tell "go f*ing learn programming" (or whatever) is probably something you don't want under your question...

Comment: @Ben: no repercussions? I've listed some in my answer.

Comment: @JonClements: Yea, I can agree with opening up the comment flags under a user's _own_ question / answer.

Comment: They're [not mentioned in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/179419) @Cerbrus. Even if there are repercussions - why do they need to be enacted for users without the privilege?

Comment: @Ben: These repercussions are automatic. We don't want to be adding exceptions on exceptions like that.

Comment: I've linked you to the FAQ that says there are none @Cerbrus. The privileges page only says posts and not comments. So I still don't know where these repercussion are coming from - could you edit your post to cite repercussions for comment flags? Is your comment about the complexity of the code or the complexity of the user experience? I'm unsure why the code is our business and the users this would affect don't need to know that additional complexity exists, if indeed it does.

Comment: _"If a comment is flagged by three users, it will be auto-soft-deleted. There is no penalty for this. Flagged comments will be surfaced to moderators, so if you have a problem with a comment, flag it."_

Comment: That's a repercussion, @Ben. These comment flags _do_ draw moderator attention to them.

Comment: So the loss of rep part of your answer is incorrect. The suspensions part I assume we trust our moderators to do the correct thing here if their attention is drawn to a "rude" comment that isn't actually rude - there are no automatic suspensions. Why can't automatic removal be limited in some way in the same way that questions currently are?

Comment: @Ben: Spam / abusive flags on questions / answers trigger ___automatic___ suspensions.

Comment: This feature request says **comments**, as pointed out by Jon in the first comment on this answer. questions/answers are not mentioned.

Comment: _" Is your comment about the complexity of the code or the complexity of the user experience?"_ Both. The more exceptions you add, the more complex the system will be to build / maintain, and the more difficult it will be to explain how things work. Keep it simple.

Comment: @Cerbrus not quite... If they reach the threshold of flags required, it deletes and locks the post, causes a 100-rep penalty to the owner of that post and feeds information to the spam-ram system. It doesn't cause any *automatic* account suspension.

Answer (score 8):

[Mat's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367623/make-comment-flagging-more-public#comment587304_367623):

> A more restricted version of this would be to allow the post author to flag comments on his question/answer rather than on any post at all. Making the flag option more visible on comments might be required too, it's not the most discoverable thing in the UI (IMO).

is something that I could get behind (I'm probably missing something obvious, but anyway, here goes).

At the moment, any registered user (regardless of rep) can always raise a custom moderator flag on their *own* post. I guess technically they could raise such a flag and say: "the comments on my post are...", but that's not likely to get seen by mods expediently and not everyone is great at wording what exactly the issue is in a completely free-form text field.

If a new comment flag type was created (and is the only available type and only visible) for <15 rep users **that was only available to be used on their own posts** and worded something along the lines of:

> Only flag this comment if it's rude, abusive or otherwise unwelcoming. **Do not flag where you disagree with the comment on its technical merits**

<sub>(wording to be worked on)</sub>

---

This'd let:

- <15 rep users to indicate there's a problem in comments
- moderators know to review that type of flag in the context of a new user and to make sure to look at the entire post in context
- staff to get some stats on how often the flag is used and the content it's used on

As to how the UI could be made more obvious/friendly/whatever to do that - I'll leave that to someone who actually knows something about UI.

Comment: _"Do not flag where you disagree with the flag on its technical merits"_  - When do users ever read that kind of warning? Let alone follow up on it?

Comment: @Cerbrus I take it that's a rhetorical question? :)

Comment: I take it that... ya know.